# Multi-Group rules in view to enforce redirect?

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm creating an internal system that needs crucial segregation. I've found myself in a position where I have to do the following:

if user is an employee AND from x company, redirect the user to this specific index.

My code looks like this in my view:

```
views.py
if request.user.groups.filter(name="Comp1" and "Employee").exists():
    return redirect("index_emp_Comp1")
elif request.user.groups.filter(name="Comp2" and "Employee").exists():
    return redirect("index_emp_Comp2")
elif request.user.groups.filter(name="Comp3" and "Employee").exists():
    return redirect("index_emp_Comp3)
```

This is during the login process.

After logging in though, every member of the 'Employee' group is redirecting to the first companies index.

Is there an alternative operator that literally equates to && in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filter(name="Comp1" and "Employee")
```

Is exactly the same as

```
filter(name="Employee")
```

Because Python evaluates the expression after the `=`, and the result of your expression is always "Employee", hence the validation of the first if statement:

```
In [16]: 'Comp1' and 'Employee'
Out[16]: 'Employee'
```

Also, you can't select groups which have two different values for a name ! I won't go into the details of every problem in this code, but a solution would be to get the list of group names first and then match them in python, ie.:

```
groups = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)

if 'Comp1' in groups and 'Employee' in groups:
  # user is in Comp1 and Employee
```

This way, you'd also be only executing one SQL request for all your conditions, rather than one per condition.

Comment: Sorry for the delay jpic, this works much better and really shows that my mindset isn't 100% in the coding world yet. I'm still learning and I've been thrown in the deep end but thoroughly enjoying it.